# $_POST is not capturing the value of any element

Tags: php, html

I am using php to simply capture the value inside a textarea and print it to body of the document. Below is the code I am using:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="post">    
    <textarea name = "ontology" value = "Copy the ontology file here...."></textarea>
    </form>
    <div id = "result">
    <?php
        echo $_POST["ontology"];
    ?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is the tragic output :( :

Notice: Undefined index: ontology in **/var/www/html/input_onto.php** on line **13**

It did not work for simple `<input>` tag too. Can anyone tell what is happening? It's silly, but I have been breaking my head for this. Please help me out and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you submit the form?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php ought to get you started, along with its *often asked* duplicate question that yours was closed with.

Comment: I never though it could be that small. I added a submit button and tried redirecting to the php file having the same php script. It worked :). Just out of curiosity- what was happening if i was not submitting it?

Comment: Nothing... the post only works when you literaly post something ...

Comment: because @Horcrux PHP is loading/looking at your POST array as soon as the page is loaded. Either use conditional statements, or use 2 different files. One for the form and one for the PHP.

Comment: what if I try to just initialize some variable with the value inside the text area? I am not posting anything in this case. @Fred-li- do you mean i'll have to use conditional like `if(isset(var))`??

Comment: @Horcrux Yes, something like that. However, it's best to use `if(!empty($_POST['var'])){...}`. `isset()` is mostly better for radio buttons/checkboxes. `empty()` checks for both conditions. The `!` is the NOT operator. Which translates to `if NOT empty` ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot @Fred-li- . As of now it works fine for me - posting and capturing the value.

Comment: you're welcome @Horcrux